# Does calling a delegate defined with a signature (e.g.) Func<t,t> type excecute synchronously in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda, expression, page-lifecycle

On first examination it appears that it does. A quick examination of the call stack shows that the method passed to the delegate is executed as one would expect. However....

In calling the delegate in a "click event" and trying to modify controls (e.g. visibility, binding, updating update panels)  nothing happens (In fact for an explicit call to an UpdatePanel.Update an exception is thrown saying that the method can not be called after Render - for all intents and purposes though, Im perceivably NOT at that stage in the page lifecycle, but rather in a control event - invariably handled as a postback event, always before Render, to my best knowledge.).

However... When returning to the call site and executing the same code (just after the delegate call) that I tried to execute (from within the method called by the delegate) to affect changes on various controls, it works.

What could be going on?

EDIT
Framework code:

```
IModalWorkflowItem
{
    void ExecuteWorkflow();
    .....
}

public abstract class BaseModalWorkflow : IModalWorkflowItem
{
    ....
    protected Func<String, IMinervaValidator , Boolean>_action;
    ....

    /// <summary>
    /// Using the properties (if necessary) perform the action
    /// required on completion of modal workflow
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>;
    protected abstract Boolean PerformAction(PropertyBag properties);
    }
```

Creation of object passing in lambda as anonymous method...

```
    new ModalWorkflowUserGroupAction(ModalPopupExtender_UserPrompt,
                   Session,
                   (x, y) =>
                     {
                         if (UserGroupManager.UserAccessToUserGroup(membershipID,
                             CurrentUserGroup.UserGroupID, false))
                         {
                             BindUserList();
```

Actual call:

```
/// <summary>
/// Call the next action in the modal workflow. 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void ExpandingButton_ModalConfirmContinue_Click
                                 (Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CurrentModalWorkFlowItem != null)
    {
        CurrentModalWorkFlowItem.ExecuteWorkflow();
```

Comment: Can you show the code how you call the delegate?

Comment: Can you show more complete code sample? Where is `ExecuteWorkflow` implemented? Where is `ModalWorkflowUserGroupAction` defined? Where is the delegate actually be invoked?

Comment: Also, could you possibly narrow this down? Is there a simpler example that reproduces the problem? And can you be more clear about what made you think that the call might be asynchronous? This sounds like it might be a misunderstanding of the page lifecycle. I recommend you turn on ASP.NET page tracing and use `Trace` to see exactly where the code is executing in the lifecycle.

Comment: I'll simplify the code.  I'll stick the trace on too. I'll gladly concede that It might be a lack of understanding of the Page Lifecycle.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, calling any delegate occurs synchronously, in any .NET program type. This sort of thing doesn't suddenly change just because you happen to be using ASP.NET.

Comment: I agree that this shouldn't just happen.  However, the execution of the method pointed to by the delegate appears to be happening outside of the normal realms of the page lifecycle. I.e. At run time something "funny" is happening....Why would a call to an UpdatePanel.Update method cause an exception to be raised saying that I am trying to do it after Render -when I am actually making the call in a post back event. This is what is causing me confusion and leading me to believe that something is out of kilter...

Comment: What else do you need? Calling delegates is always synchronous. The fact that you're calling it from ASP.NET doesn't change the behavior of .NET to suddenly change synchronous to asynchronous. .NET doesn't behave differently from one kind of program to another. Ever.

Comment: I was hoping for a brief insight into the differences (if any?) of a stock delegate type and action/func and whether this would shed light on any possible solutions/ ideas about the problem. But maybe you're right I should scrutinise the page lifecycle a little more closely....

Comment: There are no differences. What makes you think there are? What are you getting at? Delegates are delegates.